# Unable to connect mysql database from php

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
 $servername = "192.168.179.130";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "rawcdr";
 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
```

The above code gives a warning Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002) A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\new_table\index.php on line 59.

The host is a different server (CentOS 7), and i have checked its reach ability. 
I have also provided special privilege in mysql server by:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '';
```

Also started the firewall service by:

```
service firewalld start
```

Checked the port 3306 is open by following command:

```
netstat -nlp | grep 3306
```

Comment: "The host is a different server, and i have checked its reachability." How? And what were the results?

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh I dont think that Dup link is actually very relevant in this situation as its talking about `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Of course the first thing to check is that the firewall on the remote machine is not blocking access on port 3306.

**But:**

The `root` user account on a MYSQL Server is by default configured so that this account can only be used from the machine running the MySQL Server instance. So by default you cannot use `root` to access the server remotely.

And that is as it should be. It is afterall the SuperUser account.

EG

```
`root`@`localhost`
```

So you are going to have to create a new user on the remote MYSQL Server instance that is allowed to connect from either any remote host **dangerous** or a specific remote host (your PC's ip address). This new account should also be setup to be allowed access with the required privilages on the database you are trying to access.

```
CREATE USER 'ayax'@'192.168.1.200' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password'
```

Or if its 5.7 server dont forget the new password expire

```
CREATE USER 'ayax'@'your-ip-address' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password' 
    PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;
```

If your ip address is allocated by a DHCP server and can change from day to day something like this would be more flexible

```
CREATE USER 'ayax'@'192.168.1.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password'
```

Comment: I have provided the proviledge.....GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ''; But still it does not work

Comment: Did you `FLUSH Privilages` or restart the MYSQL server

Comment: Yes, restarted lampp/ mysql server

Comment: Have you checked the firewall on the remote server

Comment: Yes, the firewalld service is running

Comment: Yes but is it allowing connections through port 3306 to the MYSQL server on that machine

Comment: How should i check for port blocking ?

Comment: Thats down to you. I dont know what firewall software you are running

Comment: Yes just checked with the command "netstat -nlp | grep 3306" its open

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('192.168.179.130', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$conn) {
  die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
          . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Urrrmmmm **localhost** He did say the MySQL Server was on a remote machine!?!?!?!?